# Get loop globally in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have setting options which has controller and I need to get some of it's data on header and footer which need to be load globally.

How do I do that?

I've read some questions in this website but none of them helped me as I expected, or I didn't get those! either way I need your help to solve this issue of mine.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain about kind of data to be shown globally ?

Comment: @SagarGautam something like social network links or copyright note simple things like that.

Comment: Can you share some code like an example of a controller function that you need this to be done for?

Comment: If contents are static then no problem, other wise you can share variables or sometime you can use php tag inside which you can determine the variable values.

Comment: You want to make a view composer and bind that to the header and footer views. Sharing with every view is vast overkill. Docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do that

but one of them that refer in laravel document is using boot

**[Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)**

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views
>   that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view
>   facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share
>   within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to
>   the  AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to
>   house them:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

you can share a variable inside boot method of AppServiceProvider.php

for example you have categories table and Category Model and you want to share it to all views

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $categories = Category::All();
        View::share('categories', 'categories');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

but if you want to have header and footer for your site simply you can use master file and extend it to other views 
[document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)

Comment: but the data in their example are static, my data are dynamic coming from database would you give me a dynamic sample please?

Comment: @RobertNicjoo it doesnt matter, I edit my answer and write a simple example to share categories for all views

Comment: should i say ` View::share` or just ` View` would be enough?

Comment: just change ```('key', 'value')``` and replace it with your variables name

Comment: Ok now I've made provider how do i call it in blade?

Comment: ```key``` is the name of your variable and you can use it in all views calling ```$key``` for example in my answer sample $categories is the variable that you can use it on views and blade files

Comment: ok, now when i call $key will return all the row but when i try to get specified  column for example `{{ $key->facebook_link }}`  will give this error `Property [facebook_link] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: @RobertNicjoo it depends on how you get data in your database use ```foreach``` or other ways to get data